# save and insert custom form as webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, custom-form

I have a list, lets call it Potatoes. This list normally offers me NewPotato.aspx, EditPotato.aspx and ViewPotato.aspx. I needed a custom edit form, so I made SubscribePotato.aspx.

How can I save this aspx page that I newly created, as a webpart, so that I can insert it into another page in a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice for display/edit/new forms is to use custom rendering template, not a custom page. For more details you can see [this post](http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=987).